# Jquery: How to modify items from inner to outer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a markup like this:

```
<div class="sentence">
    <ul title="list 3">
        <li>
            <ul title="list 1">
                <li> A </li>
                <li> B </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul title="list 2">
                <li> 1 </li>
                <li> 2 </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul title="list n">
             .....
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have a function that makes some changes into the elements inside the list. This function is quite large, so to illustrate the problem it could simplify to something like this:

```
$("div.sentence ul").each(function() {
    var mid = $(this).children("li").map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get().join(',');
    $(this).replaceWith(mid);
});
```

*As you can see, this function has no sense. That's just an example in order to show some example. Probably, that doesn't work.*

The problem is that function works only when I have only a list (*ul*). When I have more than one list it doesn't work because `$("div.sentence ul")` returns a list of *ul* elements where the first one is the outer *ul* and the last one is the last one in reading order (I believe, also I don't know if this order is guaranted or if it will change in the next Jquery version).

The question is I need to get first the inner lists (not a problem the order) and then the outer ones. For instance, in this example, I need to get the list tittled "list 1", then "list 2" and the last one should be "list 3". Is possible to get the *ul*s in this order?

Comment: You cannot get the inner lists before the outer list if you also want the outer list. jquery always returns elements in document order unless using a few specific methods such as prevUntil where they get returned in reverse order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hnsf3/3/).

Basically, you need a [Depth-first traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Depth-first_traversal) (Postorder).

I played a bit with the selectors, mainly with the [child-selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) to get only the children of the next level, not all until the leaves, this for every ul:

```
function foo(ctx) {
  $(ctx).find(">ul").each(function() {
      foo($(">li", this));
      alert($(this).attr('title'));
  });
}

foo("div.sentence");​
```

Answer (score 0):

With the specific html posted, you can do something like this:

```
$(".sentence > ul").each(function(){

    $(this).find("ul").each(function(){
       // do something with inner lists
    });

    // do something with the outer
});
```

Or like this:

```
$(".sentence ul ul").each(function(){
    // do something with inner lists
});

$(".sentence > ul").each(function(){
    // do something with the outer
});
```

The first could be made recursive if you need multiple levels using `>`.